# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: No filter named 'human_format'

Tags: flask, jinja2

I'm new to Jinja/Flask and am getting this error when trying to use my filter in my template.

My filter:

```
def human_format(num):
    num = float('{:.3g}'.format(num))
    magnitude = 0
    while abs(num) >= 1000:
        magnitude += 1
        num /= 1000.0
    return '{}{}'.format('{:f}'.format(num).rstrip('0').rstrip('.'), ['', 'K', 'M', 'B', 'T'][magnitude])
```

It tests okay with some basic input values.

I then import it into my app with `from filters import human_format`

My route:

```
@app.route("/list")
def list():

    env = jinja2.Environment()
    env.filters['human_format'] = human_format
    for f in env.filters:
        print(f) # I can see my function listed here
    print(human_format(4232300000)) # I can see an output value here
```

In my template:

`<td>{{ company[6] | human_format}}</td>`

What am I doing wrong? I am using Flask 2.0.3 and Jinja2 3.0.3

Comment: I haven't used `jinja2.Environment` before. Try putting this decorator above your filter: `@app.template_filter('human_format')` instead. Works for me

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried that but that didn't work. Is it because I'm importing my filter from another file? How do I get around that?

Comment: No your filters are fine to be in another file. Make sure you're importing the `app` var. Try a built-in filter like `length` to see if that works maybe? Then work backwards

Answer (score 0):

Use the global jnja2 environment of the Flask application. You can add your own filter to this by assigning it by name to the "filters" dictionary.
You can find this in the documentation under ["Registering Filters"](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/templating/#registering-filters).

```
def human_format(num):
    num = float('{:.3g}'.format(num))
    magnitude = 0
    while abs(num) >= 1000:
        magnitude += 1
        num /= 1000.0
    return '{}{}'.format('{:f}'.format(num).rstrip('0').rstrip('.'), ['', 'K', 'M', 'B', 'T'][magnitude])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_env.filters.update(human_format = human_format)
```